# Magnitude of a few points in fft2 for a 2D image not getting retained after modification

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, fft

I am new to the concept of using FFT for 2D images and seemed to have stuck at a point.

I am converting an image to the Fourier space and setting some coordinates (or magnitudes of the frequency) to a value (say 0.1). After that modification, observing the fft values shows 1.00000000e-01 for the modified coordinates.

Now when I save the image after modifications and re-transform the newly saved image to the Fourier space, the values of all the points that I had changed to 1.00000000e-01 are not getting retained.

Assume, I have the grey_scale_image initially. Following is the snippet:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from scipy import fftpack
import imageio
import numpy
import math

fft2 = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(grey_scale_image))

chosen_coordinates = [(287, 112), (287, 162), (287, 212), (812, 162), (837, 137), (112, 212), (137, 137), (662, 137), (662, 162)]

for (i,j) in chosen_coordinates:
    fft2[i, j] = 0.1

imageio.imsave('fft_after_change.jpg',
                   (numpy.log(abs(fft2)) * 255 /
                    numpy.amax(numpy.log(abs(fft2)))).astype(numpy.uint8))

ifft2 = abs(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.ifftshift(fft2)))

imageio.imsave('new_image.jpg', ifft2.astype(numpy.uint8))

# transforming the 'new_image' now

fft2 = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(new_image))

# On exploring the values of the chosen coordinates above, the fft2 does not retains the value (0.1) for those points that was set earlier.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: "Not retained" What does this mean? Do you see the values that were there before you assigned 0.1, or do you see values close to 0.1 but not exactly?

Comment: On transforming the image first time and observing the value, it was -3009.94386863-20638.02909566j. After changing it to 0.1, it became 1.00000000e-01+0.j. And after saving the modified image followed by fft of it, the value of the same point became 297.76299692 -7699.36424684j.

Comment: fourier transforms contain COMPLEX numbers, of wildly varying magnitudes. don't store that stuff as a picture.

Comment: Well, there are two things: you take the magnitude of the IFFT, meaning you throw away information that surely affects the frequency domain, and you introduce JPEG compression artifacts, which will corrupt frequency components with small magnitude like the ones you are looking at.

Comment: So are you suggesting me to not use abs in the IFFT and use png instead? If yes, then I tried not using abs in the FFT, but it gave a warning stating 'Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part'. Also, I tried using png format. Doing these two, the values have grown higher than before and they are not even close to 0.1.